# How to create a search function using html

Tags: php, html

I have a 120mb text file that has data in the form of

```
(entry name) | (entry data)
(entry name2) | (entry data2)
(entry name3) | (entry data3>)
```

and so on for a couple hundred thousand entries. Each entry is separated by a return

I want to create a search engine in html that scans the text file for matches based on the entry names and data.

For example: if I type in `entry name2` or any string that is a subset of `entry name2` or `entry data2` into my search bar, the html page should return:

> The entry data for `entry name2` is `entry data2`

It should also return matches for other entries such as `entry name3` as well if the string entered into the search bar is a subset of both `entry name2` and `entry name3`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML is a markup language, not a programming language. You can't do this in HTML. You'd have to use something like PHP (server side) or Javascript (client side). Also, you surely don't want to store all of that data in just a text file. A linear search with that many entries could take forever. Use some sort of DB.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve that using only `HTML`.

What you're requesting is a capability available only with server side languages (especially if we're talking about a dynamic list). You should be acquainted with server-side languages (PHP etc) and learn how to do it with them.